# Trying to create a small Image Gallery in Action Script

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, gallery

I'm new to Flash and AS3 and I'm trying to make an image gallery. For some reason it .. doesn't do anything.

I have 2 buttons: back & next and a Dynamic Text field for loading progress. zonaAfisare_mc is the container for the images.
It doesn't load any image, here's the code:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;

var source:*; 
var loader:Loader; 
var loaderIndex:Number = 1; 

next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadNext);
back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadPrev);

function loadIt()
    {

        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onLoadingProgress); 
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,initHandler);          
        addChild(loader);           
        loadImage();
    }


function initHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        source = loader.content;
        source.alpha = 0;
        source.x = zonaAfisare_mc.x;
        source.y = zonaAfisare_mc.y;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
    }
function onLoadingProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
        var percentage:Number=(evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal)*100;
        var total_percentage:Number=Math.floor(percentage);
        loaded.text=total_percentage.toString()+" %";
    }

function loadNext(event:Event):void
    {
        if (loaderIndex = 5) {
            loaderIndex = 1
            loadImage();
        } else {            
            loaderIndex = loaderIndex + 1; 
            loadImage();
        }
    }
function loadPrev(event:Event):void
    {
        if (loaderIndex = 1) {
            loadImage();
        } else {
            loaderIndex = loaderIndex - 1; 
            loadImage();
        }
    }



function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        if( source.alpha < 1 ){ 
            source.alpha += .1;
        }else{
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
        }
    }

function getPath():String
    {
        return ("images/image"+loaderIndex+".jpg");
    }
function loadImage():void
    {
        loader.load(new URLRequest(getPath()));
    }
loadIt();
```

Comment: You need to debug the code to figure out more specifically what's going wrong, read up on ActionScript debugging for the tool your using (as in Flash IDE, Flash Builder, FDT, etc. an article or two should do) http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html once you know how to add traces to your code and use breakpoints you can figure out what error is occurring then get help.

Comment: You need to load images from a HTTP server, not from local disk.